# Dynamically Resize forms and controls inspite of change in Display size (Small/Medium/Large) in VB.net

Tags: vb.net, winforms, windows

We have developed windows application which is including many forms and controls with default small display size and it is working fine.
but in client systems,displays are not consistent. so when the same code runs with medium/large screen size, the controls are overlapping

It would be great help if anyone gives solution for dynamic re-size/fit the form & controls for any display (small-100%, medium-125%, large-150%)

and also Is there any way to find the Display size (small-100%, medium-125%, large-150%) in vb.net

You can change display size in control-Panel.

Comment: You should not have overlaping controls with different display sizes, unless you set manually the position and size of the controls. Use percent for the size and position for each control instead of fixed values. eg if the width of a control is 20% of the form width it should remain 20%

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Anchor property to automatically adjust the control size according to its form size. You can anchor any side of the control to that side of the form. For example, if I anchor all four sides of a picturebox to the form, the picturebox will mimic the shape of the form when the form is resized. If you anchor only the top and the bottom of the picturebox, for example, it will change height with the form, but the width and horizontal position will remain constant.

Answer (score 0):

Finally found a solution by doing R&D

call the below function in the Form_Load like ScaleForm(me)

```
 Public Sub ScaleForm(WindowsForm As System.Windows.Forms.Form)
        Using g As System.Drawing.Graphics = WindowsForm.CreateGraphics
            Dim sngScaleFactor As Single 
            Dim sngFontFactor As Single = 1
            If g.DpiX > 96 Then
                sngScaleFactor = g.DpiX / 96
                'sngFontFactor = 96 / g.DpiY
            End If
            If WindowsForm.AutoScaleDimensions = WindowsForm.CurrentAutoScaleDimensions Then
                'ucWindowsFormHost.ScaleControl(WindowsForm, sngFontFactor)
                WindowsForm.Scale(sngScaleFactor)
            End If
        End Using
    End Sub
```